# React Navigation 6.x - How to trigger navigation in parent navigator, and how to trigger method in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app with a [nested navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators) structure like so:

```
StackA
  -- Tabs
    -- StackB
```

1. From `StackB`, is there a cleaner way to trigger a navigation on `StackA` than `navigation.getParent().getParent().navigate(...)`? (eg: From within the `News` component, navigate `StackA -> Article`)
2. From `StackA` or `Tab`, how could I trigger a method on a screen within `StackB`? (eg: When pressing the `Home` tab button, trigger a method inside the `News` component)

My code looks something like:

```
function App () {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator> {/* StackA */}
        <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Tabs} /> /* Tab */
        <Stack.Screen name="article" component={Article} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

function Tabs () {
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.screen name="home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.screen name="search" component={Search} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

function Home () {
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator> /* StackB */
      <Stack.screen name="news" component={News} />
      <Stack.screen name="archive" component={Archive} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: Umhh, what do you mean by `from news, navigate StackA to Article`? Do you want to navigate from `News` (while you are currently in it) to `Article`?

Comment: Sorry I edited it to hopefully make it a bit clearer and also adjusted the code, the idea is when viewing a list of `News` items, pressing one should open to `Article` by calling `StackA`'s navigate method - which works with multiple `getParent()` calls but feels messy - ideally I would be able to call that navigator from anywhere.

Comment: why do you need to call `getParent()`? `navigate` works fine to navigate to a screen in parent navigator